# Understanding DEM of difference results in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, lidar, rivers

I am looking at channel change in a river in the UK and am using three DTM rasters to observe change over time. One of the methods I am using is to simply minus one DTM from another.
I have got the results but I am unsure how to interpret them.
I believe the numbers are in mm.

EDIT:
So I have made sure that the DTMs are in the same co-ordinate system (British National Grid) and are alligned. Looking at the properties, it suggests that the scale is in metres? So what do the numbers represent e.g. scale +614 to +573168 for the 1998 DTM.

Even if the scale is incorrect and in fact is in millimetres, does this suggest areas that are eroded could have been so at 18,000mm (or 18 metres)? This seems too high as the river itself is only 0.5 metres deep.
(for the DTM of difference, the scale is between +18662 and -18492).

[DTM 1998](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIzYx.png)

[DTM 2009](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycs4x.png)

[DTM 2009 - DTM 1998](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UUSe.png)

[Example of the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiDfv.png)

Answer (score 3):

Millimeters are a good guess, but to be sure, open up both of the DTM properties and examine the results.  Within the properties section, you'll see the units (meters, feet, mm, furlongs, etc) that the raster values represent.

While you're reviewing the properties, confirm that both rasters are in the same Coordinate Reference System (if not, project one or both so that their CRSs are identical), and that their values (discussed above) are in the same units.  Furthermore, both rasters must be 'snapped' together, so that cells from one year align exactly (in the x-y dimensions) with the other year.

Once you've confirmed all of the above, your subtraction method is appropriate.  The output values will be in the same units that were specified in the raster properties.  In the case of 1998 minus 2009 (assuming that your raster values represent elevation), positive values indicate a loss of elevation between years, and negative values indicate a gain in elevation.  Zero represents no change.

Since your example displays a river basin, I'd venture to guess that positive values indicate areas that have scoured out, and negative areas represent streambed deposition.

Changing your symbology from B&W to a two-color symbology would really help to visualize the change.  A red -> blue color ramp, for example, would more dramatically show the evulsion -> deposition effect.

Comment: So I have made sure that the DTMs are in the same co-ordinate system (British National Grid) and are alligned. Looking at the properties, it suggests that the scale is in metres? So what do the numbers represent e.g. scale +614 to +573168 for the 1998 DTM.

Even if the scale is incorrect and in fact is in millimetres, does this suggest areas that are eroded could have been so at 18,000mm (or 18 metres)? This seems too high as the river itself is only 0.5 metres deep. (for the DTM of difference, the scale is between +18662 and -18492).

Comment: From the question mark at the end of your second sentence, it appears that you are unsure what the raster cell values represent.  When coupled with the +/- 18 meter difference range, I can understand your puzzlement.  At this point you should refer back to your data source to assess the data properties.  Look for a *metadata* file, which will describe the data's provenance, intended purposes, and values.  I think that your difference methodology is correct, but there certainly appears to be something odd about the data. Please stay in touch!